# How to receive & process chunked data to show a status with angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I need some help with an approach using angularjs.

The rest server is giving me multiple instances of status record representing a long running server process. The server is returning the data in chunked form. The web page needs to show the status information for each returned record chunk.

I think I need to use promises, but I don't know how to process each record arriving as a chunk.

I would like to avoid any dependency on jquery. Also, rewriting the server rest interface is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

If server return array of records, send request and save response in an array and use `ng-repeat` to show your array.

make your `$http` request and in success callback push new items to an array and use `ng-repeat`:

```
$http({
    ...
})
.success(function(data, status, headers, config){
      recordsArray.push(data);
}).
error(function(data, status, headers, config){

});

<ul>
   <li ng-repeat="record in recordsArray">{{record.title}}</li>
</ul>
```

Also it is better to use `$http` in a service.

Comment: Thanks Mo,  I'll give it a try once the server is 'back up' :)

Comment: Sorry to take so long to get back to you, I had to pickup the server code to fix it.. be back soon